# Lodash Usage Optimization

Tags: javascript, refactoring, lodash

Hello i have an JSON Object as following:

```
{
  "serviceItemPriceList": [
    {
      "commissionalPrice": 2,
      "currencyType": {
        "type": "EUR",
        "languageKey": "enum.currency_type.EUR"
      },
      "id": 10,
      "officialPrice": 2,
      "vat": 5
    },
    {
      "commissionalPrice": 1,
      "currencyType": {
        "type": "TRY",
        "languageKey": "enum.currency_type.TRY"
      },
      "id": 9,
      "officialPrice": 1,
      "vat": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

lets call it `obj`... And i want to get an output as following:

```
[
  {
    "id": 10,
    "currencyType": {
      "type": "EUR",
      "languageKey": "enum.currency_type.EUR"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "currencyType": {
      "type": "TRY",
      "languageKey": "enum.currency_type.TRY"
    }
  }
]
```

I have a working code to achieve this:

```
lodash(obj.serviceItemPriceList).map(
  function (serviceItemPrice) {
    return lodash(serviceItemPrice).pick(['id', 'currencyType']).value();
  }
).value();
```

My question is: Is there any better/shorter/smarter way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is a short "pure" Javascript approach without lodash library, if you assume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short *"pure"* JavaScript solution using `Array.prototype.map()` function:

```js
var obj = {"serviceItemPriceList":[{"commissionalPrice":2,"currencyType":{"type":"EUR","languageKey":"enum.currency_type.EUR"},"id":10,"officialPrice":2,"at":5},{"commissionalPrice":1,"currencyType":{"type":"TRY","languageKey":"enum.currency_type.TRY"},"id":9,"officialPrice":1,"at":10}]};

var result = obj.serviceItemPriceList.map(function (o) {
    return {id: o.id, currencyType: o.currencyType};
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @ZeRubeus just fyi, MDN is just a tutorial site. `.map` is a part of JS array functions. Not sure about optimisation thing

Comment: @ZeRubeus, "pure" JavaScript means core JavaScript, which will go faster than any library, saving bandwidth and getting fast responses

Comment: Really??  I know that pure js means core js but I don't believe it's faster just because it's core js

Comment: Go to the v8 doc and look how the engine resolve map u'll understand what I mean

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is short enough already, I'd only suggest removing unnecessary `.value` calls, because you're not using chaining.

```
_.map(obj.serviceItemPriceList, item => _.pick(item, ['id', 'currencyType']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array of keys that needs to be a part of result and the use `.map` + `.reduce` to return new object.

**Note:** purpose of having an array is to reduce hardcoding.

```js
var obj={serviceItemPriceList:[{commissionalPrice:2,currencyType:{type:"EUR",languageKey:"enum.currency_type.EUR"},id:10,officialPrice:2,vat:5},{commissionalPrice:1,currencyType:{type:"TRY",languageKey:"enum.currency_type.TRY"},id:9,officialPrice:1,vat:10}]};

var returnKeyList = ["currencyType", "id"]
var r = obj.serviceItemPriceList.map(function(o){
  return returnKeyList.reduce(function(p,c){
    p[c] = o[c];
    return p;
  }, {})
});

console.log(r)
```

Note: `currencyType` is a object and objects are passed by reference, so changing `r[i].currencyType` will reflect in original array. To avoid this, try following:

```js
var obj={serviceItemPriceList:[{commissionalPrice:2,currencyType:{type:"EUR",languageKey:"enum.currency_type.EUR"},id:10,officialPrice:2,vat:5},{commissionalPrice:1,currencyType:{type:"TRY",languageKey:"enum.currency_type.TRY"},id:9,officialPrice:1,vat:10}]};

var returnKeyList = ["currencyType", "id"]
var r = obj.serviceItemPriceList.map(function(o){
  return returnKeyList.reduce(function(p,c){
    p[c] = typeof(o[c]) === "object" ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o[c])) : o[c];
    return p;
  }, {})
});

console.log(r)
```